# What rabbinic/Judaic scholar has the lowest Erdős number? 

Tags: history, rabbis, books-generally, number

[From Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erdos_number)

> The Erdős number describes the "collaborative distance" between a person and mathematician Paul Erdős, as measured by authorship of mathematical papers. ... 
>   Due to the very high frequency of interdisciplinary collaboration in science today, very large numbers of non-mathematicians in many other fields of science also have finite Erdős numbers.[7] For example, political scientist Steven Brams has an Erdős number 2. In biomedical research, it is common for statisticians to be among the authors of publications, and many statisticians can be linked to Erdős via John Tukey, who has Erdős number 2. Similarly, the prominent geneticist Eric Lander and the mathematician Daniel Kleitman have collaborated on papers,[8][9] and since Kleitman has an Erdős number of 1,[10] a large fraction of the genetics and genomics community can be linked via Lander and his numerous collaborators.  ... many linguists have finite Erdős numbers ...

Sooo ...

Which rabbi/Judaic scholar has the lowest Erdos number? And which rabbi/Judaic scholar forms the best "bridge" for other scholars, as Eric Lander does for geneticists?

Comment: Are big-time Jewish authors — really big-time, like _rishonim_ or early _acharonim_ or the _Gra_ or the author of the _Tanya_ — known to have ever collaborated? Can anyone name any who have, and with whom?

Comment: @msh210, I was focusing on contemporaries or near-contemporaries. Lehavdil, the same problem occurs in mathematics -- people didn't co-author papers a few centuries ago. The earliest mathematician with a known Erdos number is Dedekind (born 1831), according to Wikipedia.

Comment: I suspect that there's a great deal more collaborative publication in academic Jewish scholarship than in Yeshivish Jewish scholarship.

Comment: And Isaac, are there people who bridge those fields?

Comment: Another possible connection (but IMO unlikely and, anyway, via medicine): Bernhard Schapiro http://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15635756.

Comment: The thing erdos says at the end sounds a lot like Torah
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1qeWugmiGt4

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if he quite counts as a "rabbinic/Judaic scholar," but [Robert Aumann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Aumann) is a [serious learner](http://www.rabbihorowitz.com/PYes/ArticleDetails.cfm?Book_ID=1172&ThisGroup_ID=262&Type=Article), has published on [Talmudic topics](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6WJ3-4CYGBRF-MG&_user=10&_coverDate=08%2F31%2F1985&_rdoc=1&_fmt=summary&_orig=browse&_sort=d&view=c&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=320a9584cc080f579d37232f48d8bac6), and has an Erdos number of [3](http://www.oakland.edu/enp/erdpaths/). If he doesn't quite count, he may yet provide your bridge, if he collaborated on a Talmud topic with someone who does.

Comment: I've e-mailed him asking for info on this question.

Comment: He responded saying that the only connections he could think of were Pinny Rabinowitz and Benjy Weiss, both mathematicians cum _talmide chachamim_, but that he doesn't know their further connections. [Note that Pinny (Philip) Rabinowitz has an Erdős number of only 2 (via Péter Vértesi FWIW).]

Comment: ...and Benjy Weiss also has Erdős number 2 (via Vitaly Bergelson).

Answer (score 3):

Other people you may want to try:

- **Rabbi Dr Moshe Tendler** & Samuel Kormin [published on a cancer drug](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v199/n4892/abs/199501a0.html).

  - Samuel Kormin has [published papers on the biological effects of radiation](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC290775/) with some physicists.
  - I couldn't track the trail beyond that, but there has to be some physicist trail to Erdos.

---

- **Professor Moshe Koppel** at Bar Ilan University has a computer science background from NYU, and has an [Erdos](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1292977) [number](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3280410) [of](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2894477) 3. Though as far as using him as a bridge, most of his Judaic publications have been solo.

---

- Philospher **Rabbi Dr. David Shatz** has done plenty of collaboration on Judaic subjects, but I haven't yet found his philosophers' link to Erdos. Though it likely exists.

---

- The late **Rabbi Dr. Azriel Rosenfeld** had an Erdos number of at most 2; he published on Judaics in *Tradition* and *AOJS*, but I don't think he ever co-authored in those.

---

- The famed trio of **Witztum, Rips, and Rosenberg** published on Bible Codes; [Rips has collaborated with Sapir](http://www.jstor.org/pss/3597195), [who has a number of at most 2](https://files.oakland.edu/users/grossman/enp/ErdosA.html). Have any of these three co-authored with any more traditional rabbinic/Judaic scholars?

---

- **Rabbi Moshe Meiselman**, rosh yeshiva of Toras Moshe, has a math background from MIT. Just checking [dissertation genealogy](http://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=67349), Meiselman was mentored by Anderson was mentored by Thomas, who in turn [mentored Helen Grundman](http://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=32704), who has [an Erdos number of at most 2](https://files.oakland.edu/users/grossman/enp/ErdosA.html). Has Rabbi Meisleman co-authored much Torah literature?

---

Comment: Re the Jewish writers whom you (R'Shalom) did not specify as generally writing solo (or ask about): are they known to have widely collaborated? Re Rabbi Meiselman: I don't think being mentored by someone counts as collaboration.

Comment: Rabbi Tendler co-authors frequently with Dr. Loicke, Dr. Rosner, and many others. Rabbi Dr. Shatz has plenty of co-authors too.

Comment: Tendler has an Erdos number of 5. You can find them all through the MS academic research portal using their "coauthor path". http://academic.research.microsoft.com/VisualExplorer#45277239&1112639